# How to import a default export of webpack entry file from outside?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I think I can best explain it with code. I have a file in webpack like the following:

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import Server from './server';

import templateFn from './template';

export default (req, res) => {
    const reactString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Server />);
    const template = templateFn(html);
    res.send(template);
};
```

I also have an express application where I want to have access to the default exported function. If it makes any difference, this file is the webpack entry file. Here is what I tried in my express app:

```
const handleRequest = require(path.resolve(webpackConfig.output.path, webpackConfig.output.filename));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(handleRequest);
});
```

I was trying to import the webpack generated file with the hope that I will be able to access the entry file's default export. Well, I was wrong as the output of the import was `{}`.

Is there a webpack plugin or some kind of a technique to do what I am trying to build? I don't want the express application to be part of the webpack build. That was the main reason I separated the code in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access contents of webpack using library parameter (webpack.config.js):

```
output: {
    path: ...,
    filename: ...,
    library: 'myapp',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
}
```

Then access it in the code:

```
const output = require(path.resolve(webpackConfig.output.path, webpackConfig.output.filename));

const defaultExportFunction = output.myapp.default;
```